# cd to last directory in oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh, terminal.app, oh-my-zsh

Is there anyway to get oh-my-zsh and Terminal to load up my last used directory?

For example I cd into `~/Desktop` then close my terminal. I'd like it to open back up into the `~/Desktop` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone reading this post nowadays, the `terminalapp` mentioned by @squarefrog doesn't work anymore.

Instead, just load `last-working-dir` in the same place and reload ZSH by typing `. ~/.zshrc` OR `source ~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an oh-my-zsh plugin that allows this called `terminalapp`.

Edit your `.zshrc` file, and go to the `plugins=` line and add in `terminalapp`. For example, `plugins=(git terminalapp)`.

Then just restart your shell.

Comment: terminalapp plugin it's depecrated. 
https://github.com/joohoi/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/terminalapp/terminalapp.plugin.zsh